# Drawing Tool in Native Android to draw Drag-gable Circle and Rectangle?

Tags: android, google-maps

Hi I want to draw drag-gable and re sizable Circle, Polygon and Rectangle on my Google Map. but there  plenty of example are based on JavaScript but **I don't want to use Java Script , I want to make it in Native Android.**
Please give me any good library link or Example. I need this badly.

My Map page should be open like this to draw Circle and Rectangle and Polygon [In such a manner](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools)

Please Help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [Shapes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes) page in the Maps for Android developer site. With it, you can create Polylines, Polygons, and Circles (very similar to the JS library; well, aside from the square)

Comment: thnxx for reply but it doesn't clear my doubts... I can draw circle , polygon and rectangle but it must be drag-gable and also should like as drawing tool as mentioned in above link.

Comment: Kind of like an overlaying view? I'm not sure if [Ground Overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay) can do the trick for the lines/shapes to be drag-gable, but I think it'll be a nice start.